# How to log into a website through android app

Tags: android

I am new to android programming, and am making an app which pulls information from a website. My current problem is logging into the website to access more webpages. I am not sure as to how to go about. I've looked at lots of different code to do this, but am not really understanding how it works. Help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a WebView as a container of your website. You cannot directly access the data inside the web view however, you can call JavaScript from Android java code. See the JavascriptInterface. Follow this links for details:

[android webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

[javascript interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WebView web = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
//creating instance
String url = "your_url";

web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//enable javascript

web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
//prevent opening browser when a link is clicked inside webview

web.loadUrl(url);
//loading the url
```